# How to add www in front of my wesite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website say **www.abcd.com**. Its working fine if i access it using url **http://abcd.com**. But what i want is that if user go with url **http://abcd.com**, then web server should be able to convert it into url **www.abcd.com**.

**%LOCATION_CONTAINS_HTACCESS_FILE% = Some Path**

Some important changes in httpd.config are:

```
1. DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"


2. <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All       #changed to All
</Directory>


3. <Directory "%LOCATION_CONTAINS_HTACCESS_FILE%">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>


4. AccessFileName .htaccess                             #default
5. %LOCATION_CONTAINS_HTACCESS_FILE%/.htaccess           # I added 
6. <Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

My **.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

With these changes I am getting error in line 5(from above, i think) when executing "**service httpd restart**":

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 415 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '%LOCATION_CONTAINS_HTACCESS_FILE%/.htaccess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I went through most of links on web, but couldn't get any specific solution to this.

I don't have much knowledge about Web services. But waiting for a simpler solution.

Hoping you guys have faced this issue & surely solved.

Comment: I tried it too, recently but didn't get it to working. Waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the snippet below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non-canonical domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www version
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```

It does two things:

1. The first snippet (below "Redirect non-canoncial domains") redirects visitors who come in from an alias (eg. my-domain-alias.com) to the main domain (yourdomain.com). It uses a 301 redirect (permanent) to let search engines know this is the right address (and not some duplicate content).
2. It checks if the www prefix is used. If not, it redirects, and also redirects using the 301 status code.

Note: the NC flag tells apache to check ignoring the case.

-- Edit:

I'd change the order directive to:

```
# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>
```

This will deny access to ALL hidden files (eg. your php .user.ini file, if present), not only .htaccess/.htpasswd files etc.

Comment: Any idea about **httpd.config** file? Is is correct.? What about the Error?

Comment: Well, I think you've grabbed the rule `<Directory "%LOCATION_CONTAINS_HTACCESS_FILE%">` from some kind of an example? Because i've actually never seen the use of a parameter over there. Guess the writer of the example just wanted you to fill in a specific directory name over there. This is actually causing the error message.

Comment: at point 2: I would not change the AllowOverride setting over there, I'd only do that in specific http directories. At 3. I'd fill in your document root directory. Point 4 is ok, remove 5 (see my comment about the parameter). 6. is perfect. In combination with my htaccess example it should work

Comment: So, do you think, "AllowOverride All" wont effect anything?

Comment: Hey @giorgio, **2: I would not change the AllowOverride setting over there, I'd only do that in specific http directories**: What is this **Specific http directories**?

Comment: with 'specific http directories' I mean directories reachable with the browser. That means, directories where for example your index.php resides.
have you changed "yourdomain.com" to your own domain name? What happens? Do you see an error in the apache error log?

Comment: Thanks @giorgio, for your help. With your help & a little from web, i now able to do.